# Get preceding sibling with Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a link that hidden the element when the page is resized, so im trying to get that element, by previous element.

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="icon icon-doc-new"></i>
        <span class="hidden-sm dropdown-label">Create</span>
        <span class="caret hidden-sm"></span>
    </a>
```

To get the "normal" element i use the Xpath :

```
.//*[@id='main-menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(), 'Create')]
```

then i would like to get element `<i class="icon icon-doc-new"></i>`
something like this

```
 .//*[@id='main-menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(), 'Create')]/precending-sibling::i[0] //(also tried different indexes]
```

Have tried a couple of other methods but with no go either.

Any tips`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath`:

```
 .//*[@id='main-menu']/li/a[span[text()="Create"]]/i
```

Comment: This worked right away. do you mind to explain it a little more why?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that there is a typo in your `XPath` expression: `precending-sibling` should be `preceding-sibling`. So your `XPath` also should be correct. I mean with `[1]` index, but not `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

So, you actually need parent element if I'm correct and not preceding sibling.

Try with `.//*[@id='main-menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(), 'Create')]/parent::a`

If you want preceding sibling then try with `.//*[@id='main-menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(), 'Create')]/precending-sibling::i`

Comment: Thank you! this works. of course now when I see it parent::a.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these below mentioned `xpath`

```
//span[@class='caret hidden-sm']/..//preceding-sibling::span[text()= 'Create']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute of `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag along with `text` method using `preceding-sibling keyword`.

> OR

```
//span[@class='caret hidden-sm']/..//preceding-sibling::span[@class='hidden-sm dropdown-label']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute of `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag along with `class` attribute using `preceding-sibling keyword`.